# Rottentomatoes' API limits

Tags: ios, json, rotten-tomatoes

I've been looking on the RT site but cannot find any details, I'm just patching it together from what I've read on forums:

It appears the rottentomatoes' API is limited to 10k calls per day (1 call each 8.64secs), per IP address. Eg with the one API key on two separate computers (different IPs), they will not affect each other's limits.

Is this true? Anyone know? It is for an iPhone app to get the background.

Comment: I've looked into RT a year ago or so and it was a horrible mess. You are probably better off just fetching there html sites and parsing them yourself into json. I actually started working on that but even their html is madness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have taken this question to the RT forum, close-voters can get busy closing this thread if you wish:

http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/123466